# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' has no attribute '_TensorLike'

Tags: python, face-recognition

I installed tensorflow 2.3.1 and keras 2.4.0 versions:
here is my code;

`from keras.models import Sequential from keras.layers import Conv2D, ZeroPadding2D, Activation, Input, concatenate from keras.models import Model from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization`

`from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D, AveragePooling2D from keras.layers.merge import Concatenate from keras.layers.core import Lambda, Flatten, Dense from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform`

`from keras.engine.topology import Layer from keras import backend as K K.set_image_data_format('channels_first') import cv2`
`import os import numpy as np from numpy import genfromtxt import pandas as pd`

`import tensorflow as from fr_utils import * from inception_blocks import *`

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt import face_recognition from PIL import Image import sys`
`from tensorflow.python.framework import ops ops.reset_default_graph() np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)`

then I wrote;

`FRmodel=faceRecoModel(input_shape=(3,96,96)) FRmodel.summary()`

THEN IT GIVES ERROR:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/myjsO.png

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was the fix

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential from keras.layers import Conv2D, ZeroPadding2D, Activation, Input, concatenate

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

from tensorflow.keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization

from tensorflow.keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D, AveragePooling2D

from tensorflow.keras.layers.merge import Concatenate

from tensorflow.keras.layers.core import Lambda, Flatten, Dense

from tensorflow.keras.initializers import glorot_uniform

from tensorflow.keras.engine.topology import Layer

from tensorflow.keras import backend as K K.set_image_data_format('channels_first')
```

Another solution could be to try reinstalling Keras and Tensorflow

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer! however, i tried it even it gives an error from tensorflow.keras.layers.normalization etc..